# Read information from project designer fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

In my Visual Studio solution, there are two projects. The first project is a web application. The second project contains tests, it [references the first project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

In the web app's project designer, under the 'web' tab, is a field ['project URL'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178108.aspx). At the moment, this happens to be completed:

```
 http://localhost:8080/shop
```

How can I access the value of this field from my code? (in particular the test project)

Comment: Why do you need the web app's URL?  You should be able to unit test controllers and repositories without making HTTP calls.  If you're trying to test something that needs web calls you should probably consider a different testing mechanism.

Comment: Seconded. There is never a case where you should need to grab the local server URL for unit testing. If this is how you're currently doing it, you're probably not doing unit tests correctly.

Comment: It's a web service. Quite reasonably, I'd like to test its responses to requests. I'm flattered by your condescension, but please could you _help_ by suggesting how to do it right?

Comment: MSDN are as clueless as I am, their [unit tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243399(v=vs.80).aspx#ExampleWebServiceTestMethod) are annotated with a hard-coded project path `[AspNetDevelopmentServer("HelloWorldServer", @"C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\Visual Studio 2005\WebSites\WebSite1")]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer… you can’t and shouldn't.  This value is just a user preference setting for Visual Studio and has nothing to do with your code or the compiler.

Having said that, the value is stored in the `ProjectName.csproj.user` file (which is just an `xml` file) so you could theoretically open the file from within your code and get the value that way.  I’m not sure when this would ever be a good idea though.